# How to handle nested array of Object in ag grid(angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in angular6 i am getting the nested array of object in the same row i need to display the multiple record for some particular field

```js
{
  "Id": "123",
  "Name": "usb",
  "email": "123@gmail.com",
  "Config": [
    {
      "config": "config1",
      "field2": "1",
      "field3": "1",
      "field4": "1",
      
    },
    {
      "config": "config2",
      "field2": "3",
      "field3": "3",
      "field4": "3",
      
    }
  ]
},
{
  "Id": "123",
  "Name": "usb",
  "email": "123@gmail.com",
  "Config": [
    {
      "config": "config1",
      "field2": "1",
      "field3": "1",
      "field4": "1",
      
    },
    {
      "config": "2",
      "field2": "3",
      "field3": "3",
      "field4": "3",
      
    },
    {
      "field1": "2",
      "field2": "3",
      "field3": "3",
      "field4": "3",
      
    }
  ]
}
```

in that above object when i reach the config field need to display like below in that config count is dynamic
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you might need to use the [CellRenderers](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/) provided by ag-grid

So in your columnDefs, for the fields like config and fields, you need to use the cellRendererFramework like below.

```
  {
    headerName: 'config',
    field: 'config',
    cellRendererFramework: YourRenderer
  }
```

and in your YourRenderer, it would be like below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-renderer',
  template: `
   <div> the way you wanted to display the config </div>
  `
})
export class YourRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  public params: ICellRendererParams;

  public agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params.value;
  }

  public refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's working but only one record is coming (ngfor retriving first record only

Comment: I did not understand. It would be better if you post your code on stackblitz and share